# Theoretically, is comparison between 0 and 255 faster than 0 and 1?

Tags: performance, comparison, bit, low-level, machine-code

From the point of view of very low level programming, **how is performed the comparison between two numbers?**

Using one byte, unsigned numbers 0, 1 and 255 are written:

```cpp
0 -----> 00000000
1 -----> 00000001
255 ---> 11111111
```

Now, what happens during the comparison between these numbers?

Using my vision as a human having learned basic programming, I could imagine the following algorithm about `==` implementation:

```cpp
b = 0
while b < 8:
    if first_number[b] != second_number[b]:
        return False
    b += 1
return True
```

Basically this is like comparing each bit step by step, and stop before the end if two bits are different.

Thus we note that the comparison stops at the first iteration compared 0 and 255, while it stops at the last if 0 and 1 are compared.

The first comparison would be 8 times faster than the second.

In practice, I doubt that is the case. But is this theoretically true? 
If not, how does the computer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware is fundamentally different from the dominant programming paradigms in that all logic gates (or circuits in general) always do their work independently, in parallel, at all times. There is no such thing as "do this, then do that", only "do this here, feed the result into the circuit over there". If there's a circuit on the chip with input A and output B, then the circuit always, continuously, updates B in accordance with the current values of A — regardless of whether the result is needed right now "in the big picture".

Your pseudo code algorithm doesn't even begin to map to logic gates well. Instead, a comparator looks like this in Verilog (ignoring that there's a built-in `==` operator):

```
assign not_equal = (a[0] ^ b[0]) | (a[1] ^ b[1]) | ...;
```

Where each XOR is a separate logic gate and hence works independently from the others. The results are "reduced" with a logical or, i.e. the output is 1 if any of the XORs produces a 1 (this too does some work in parallel, but the critical path is longer than one gate). Furthermore, all these gates exist in silicon regardless of the specific bit values, and the signal has to propagate through about (1 + log w) gates for a w-bit integer. This propagation delay is again independent of the intermediate and final results.

On some CPU families, equality comparison is implemented by subtracting the two numbers and comparing the result to zero (using a circuit as described above), but the same principle applies. An adder/subtracter doesn't get slower or faster depending on the values.

Not to mention that instructions in a CPU can't take less than one clock cycle anyway, so even if the hardware would finish more quickly, the next instruction still wouldn't start until the next tick.

Now, *some* hardware operations can take a variable amount of time, but that's because they are state machines, i.e. sequential logic. *Technically* one could implement the moral equivalent of your algorithm with a state machine, but nobody does that, it's harder to implement than the naive, un-optimized combinatorial circuit above, and less efficient to boot.

State machine circuits are circuits with memory: They store their current state and always compute the outputs (depending on the current state) and the next state (depending on current state and inputs) each clock cycle. On some inputs they may go through N states until they produce an output, and N+x on other inputs. ALU operations generally don't do that though. Pipeline stalls, branch mispredictions, and cache misses are common reasons one instruction takes longer than usual in some circumstances. Properly reasoning about these in a way that helps programmers write faster code is hard though: You have to take into account all the tricky and quirks of *real* hardware, and there's a lot of those. Empirical evidence, i.e. benchmarking a real black box CPU, is vital.

Answer (score 3):

A comparison between integers is tipically implemented by the cpu as a subtraction, whose result sign contains information about which number is bigger.

While a naive implementation of subtraction executes one bit at a time (because every bit needs to know the carry of the preceding one), tipical implementation use a carry-lookahead circuit that allows the calculation of more result bits at the same time.

So, the answer is: no, every comparison takes almost the same time for every possible input.

Comment: Note that even the "naive implementation" (ripple-carry adder) takes the same amount of time regardless of the values of the inputs. And what's the "almost" doing in the last sentence? It takes exactly k clock cycles (often k = 1) period.

Answer (score 0):

When it gets down to the assembly the `cmp` instruction is used regardless of the contents of the variables.

So there is no performance difference.